# Special Price not showing in cart or checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm running Magento 1.9.2.4, you can see it live here: http://pleb.city/studio

We've set up special prices for each product such that 2 days before each booking, prices get reduced by 10%. You can see the prices for the next two days are reduced on the site. But when you add them to your cart or checkout, you get charged the normal amount.

I've found other answers which refer to the getFinalPrice()function but I can't work out which code to change in the backend.